error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not satisfied
I am trying to build a solana program but get this error.
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: spl_discriminator::discriminator::SplDiscriminate` is not satisfied

the dependencies I have are as follows:
[package]
name = "cumulus_delta_v2"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"
rust-version = "1.75.0"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "cumulus_delta_v2"

[features]
default = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
idl-build = ["anchor-lang/idl-build", "anchor-spl/idl-build"]

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["idl-build", "init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["idl-build"]}
spl-token-2022 = "5.0.2"
solana-program = "2.0.13"
spl-discriminator = "0.3.0"
spl-tlv-account-resolution = "0.8.1"
spl-transfer-hook-interface = "0.8.2"
spl-type-length-value = "0.6.0"
spl-pod = "0.4.0"


I have look at the other answers on here but am unable to make any sense of it.

I was able to isolate this to an incompatibility between the newest SPL libraries and Anchor. Since Anchor 0.30.1 uses spl-token-2022 v3 and solana-program v1.18, you'll need to bump down a few other dependencies.
I got this to work:
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["idl-build", "init-if-needed"]}
anchor-spl = {version = "0.30.1", features = ["idl-build"]}
spl-token-2022 = "3.0.0"
solana-program = "=2.0.13"
spl-discriminator = "0.2.0"
spl-tlv-account-resolution = "0.6.0"
spl-transfer-hook-interface = "0.6.0"
spl-type-length-value = "0.4.0"
spl-pod = "0.2.0"

